# What's the file size limit for Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I hope you are having a good day so far.

I was wondering, is there a hard word limit in Word? For example, can I write an encyclopedia in it and not worry about anything but CPU and memory? I know that it says there is a 32MB pure-text limit on the Microsoft website, but I have successfully surpassed the 32MB mark. I'm doing a huge project and I don't want to fint out that the program I'm writing in can't hold all my thoughts. (I tried HTML Help, but since it's 32-bit, it's out of the question)

Here's the screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Just in case it is useful, Word is using 870.2 MB of RAM and it is full of Lorem Ipsum text. I'm on Windows 11, but it would be nice to know if this limit is active on macOS as well.

Thanks in advance and enjoy the rest of your day. ✌️

Comment: Why don't you use a program known for handling large files? EmEditor comes to mind, but there are others.

Comment: That's a plaintext editor. This is an MS Word question. I've seen things like PilotEdit, it's basically the same thing as EmEditor, expensive and proprietary all the way. Btw, I'm not willing to put forth a penny. I'm also not looking for alternatives. I'm just asking about the hard limit in WORD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft clearly states this 32 MB limit (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/operating-parameter-limitation)

Whether it's hard or soft and how it's calculated is not mentioned.

However, the real limitation here is performance. Once you get a real document - with table of contents, references, maybe even pictures, tables and charts - it'll start performing very slow as you're increases.

Over time it'll just reach a level to be practically useless.

(I reached that level with documents of 100 - 200 pages, however it strongly depends on structure and content)

Comment: The 32 MB limit is in the “Visual Basic for Applications limits” section, whatever that may be referring to. The other sections list much higher limits (512 MB).

Comment: @DanielB , I think you’re right. So basically I left word copying and pasting overnight and there’s still no error, just really high CPU/RAM usage and it takes forever to manually type a dot (.) So I guess the true limitation is the hardware itself. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

### A hard limit is 32 Mb of *text*. Word can open a file up to 512 Mb total file size.

You exceed these at your peril. When you exceed the limits, Word will not open the file and it may be unrecoverable.* There is no limit on number of words, *per se*. Images and document structure can add extensively to the document size without exceeding this limit. *Several things like bookmarks and fields can number in the billions in theory. [Operating parameners of Microsoft Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/operating-parameter-limitation) How those number could be reached within the 512 Mb file size, though exceeds my imagination.*

The biggest component to add file size will be **images**, especially when you edit them in Word. Macros/vba can add to file size but it will not be significant. For instance, here is a comparison of two versions of the Normal template, both without any text.
[image: screenshot of file explorer comparison of two Normal.dotm files] The larger version contains more than a thousand macros divided into 53 modules. This adds less than a Mb to the file size. I do not know if the macros count toward the 32Mb limit.

**That answers your question.** ***Let's talk a bit more about about accomplishing your objective to create a large document in Word, though.*** As files get larger in Word, they become sluggish and harder to edit. There are things you can do to make large documents more manageable, though.

Like a physical Encyclopedia is split into volumes and Wikipedia is split into web pages, to do a full Encyclopedia in Word, you would want to split it up. *Have you ever worked with a single-volume unabridged Oxford dictionary?*

DO NOT USE [THE MASTER DOCUMENT FEATURE](https://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart). Word can handle very large documents in a single file. If you want to combine your parts into a single file for some reason, convert to pdf and use Adobe Acrobat or another pdf editor to combine the files.

You can make your Word document more manageable by:

1. [Using styles for all formatting](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm).

> Styles are arguably the most important feature in Microsoft Word.

2. Avoiding manual page breaks. Instead, use page-break-before paragraph formatting in a style.
3. Avoiding unnecessary Section breaks. If you want to have headers and footers that track page content, use [StyleRef fields](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF).
4. Making use of the [Built-In Heading Styles](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm) to organize your document. *(See also [Moving/Reorganizing Pages in Word](https://addbalance.com/word/MovePages.htm#PageStart).)* This allows you to maximize the utility of the Navigation Pane and Tables of Contents.
5. Having any automatic numbering of headings, etc. tied to styles following the directions in [Shauna Kelly's Page on Outline Numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html). The same applies to [multilevel bullets](http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html).
6. [Using Tables and Tabs for organizing text horizontally](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/4UseTablesTabs.htm).
7. [Avoiding empty paragraphs.](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/concepts/rules_enterparagraphs.html) These add complexity and make editing harder. To space paragraphs vertically, use the space-before and space-after paragraph formatting in the styles you are using.
8. Running on a beefy computer with 16Gb+ of RAM and both your document and Word on an SSD Drive.
9. Whenever possible, placing images in-line with text.
10. Any time you are thinking you want to use a Text Box (Insert > Text Box) explore use of a [Frame](https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage) or a [Table](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/tables.htm) instead. Word runs more smoothly with these constructs.

Following the above steps will make your document file smaller and easier to edit and use. Using these principles, I've edited documents that exceed 5000 pages of text.

11. Unless you need new features, using Word 2003 or Word 2010. *Both are out of support, though.* Every new edition of Word becomes more bloated with features you may not need and which will slow down performance. The .docx file format is preferable to the .doc format. It is smaller and much more recoverable.
12. When writing new parts, considering creating the new part as a separate document, using the same [template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm) and [styles](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm). Then, when almost complete, copy and paste into the main document.
13. Again, avoiding use of the [Master Documents "Feature"](https://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart).
14. Making regular backups, including to media stored off-site. That way, if you do exceed the 32 Mb limit, you will be able to use your backup rather than possibly losing your work.
15. Not editing your document when it is on a USB Flashdrive/memory
    stick. I would also avoid editing in cloud storage, stick to your hard drive when editing.

All of the above links (except to Shauna Kelly's pages and the operating parameters) are to pages on my website that expand on these ideas.

** I expect that an oversize document in .docx format could be opened in a text editor or and XML editor and pared down. That would be a huge task, in itself, though.

Comment: but for such huge documents it's still better to use a different format such as [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)

Comment: Better in what way? Does LaTex have the features and structure of Word? I am unfamiliar with LaTex. Do not take my question as criticism.

Comment: LaTeX has all the features of Word and more. You can customize everything. It's most commonly used for writing papers and printing/doing typesets. The most notable feature is tables and images won't be moved around like in Word

Comment: "LaTeX is not a word processor! Instead, LaTeX encourages authors not to worry too much about the appearance of their documents but to concentrate on getting the right content. " **Introduction to LaTex**  It may well be a terrific program, but it is not the equivalent of Word.