MS Word performance issues when editing large files
The problem: MS Word is very slow and freezes for a few minutes when editing large document [.DOCX] (1000+ pages). I've been unable to work on this document due to this issue for a couple of months now.
Efforts to solve this issue
Tried recommendations on:

MS Community.
superuser forums.
superuser forums.



Set priority on Task Manager as HIGH or REAL TIME.
Used MS Word and LibreOffice on Mac.
Used LibreOffice on Linux.


Specs:

Document size: 8.45 MB (8,866,235 bytes)
MS Office LTSC Pro Plus 2021, Ver 2108 (build 14332.20685).
Windows 11 Enterprise, Ver 23H2 (OS build 22631.3447).
i7-10700T 8C/16T @2.0GHz.
32GB RAM.
Samsung M.2 512GB NVMe.


Please let me know if I missed any details that would help resolve this issue.
Thanks.

(Please tell/add the actual size of your file on disk). A guess; your 1000 page document consist of a very large amount of data, tables, pictures and so on. Then this is either beyond the capabilities of Word, or a "Need More RAM" -problem (word causing extensive use of paging).

The amount of data (RAM) the handling (editing) of the file requires might be indicated by: Print the document to a file, check the SIZE of that file. (That "print" will propably take a long time)

Does this answer your question? Large document is sluggish and its pictures not visible in Web Layout

Here are the Operating parameter limitations and specifications in Word

Actually Word .docx files are a collection of XML files zipped up. Unzip the files and start extracting pictures and text from the XML until it works as suggested here by Microsoft - Error: "Word cannot open this file because it is larger than 512 Megabytes" when opening a document in Word

@Hannu: the file size is 8.45 MB (8,866,235 bytes), it does have some images and a content table. "Need More RAM" is an exaggeration, Word doesn't consume more than 500MB of RAM & <30% CPU.

@harrymc: Unfortunately, no. I made a copy of the document and attempted those recommendations and still no change.

@MT1: The document in question doesn't come close to 1/8 of those thresholds, so no. Never heard of that concept about Word documents, but I'm not interested in that approach.

@error404 Thanks for getting back. In that case I would say that your problem is that the document has been edited with three (maybe more?) different pieces of software MS Word and LibreOffice on Mac and LibreOffice on Linux although the last two should be the same. MS Word is trying to understand the standard approach of LibreOffice and the other way round. As a result it takes MS Word ages to work though a mangled (from MS point of view) document and so it slows down.

From my own experience for example Excel on Mac is not the same program as Excel on Windows and doesn't cope with the different standards and approach on the Mac. If you ever do get to open the document again in Word, stick to editing it with the Windows version of Word. Good luck!

@MT1: This document was initially created on MS Word version that I'm using now, and I used a USB drive to open it on other OSes as stated in OP. So, I don't believe that could be the problem in this case. Yeah, the Mac version of MS Office Suite is not the same as the Windows one but they do operate the same though. I tried Adobe Acrobat Pro and it's a terrible way to edit a word doc. Also, I tried MS Publisher but it couldn't open the document.  Since there is no fix for this issue (at the moment), are there any applications that can be used to edit this document?

@error404 are there any applications that can be used to edit this document? yes, Notepad for Windows. Unzip the .docx and go from there. Try to "correct" the XML, the differences in standards should be obvious! You are aiming to make the document editable on MS Word for Windows.

Further, it would be interesting to see if Notepad++ with an XML UDL for syntax highlighting can understand the document.

Notepad++ User Defined Languages

also, Visual Studio Code is probably good at displaying and editing XML to Microsoft "standards".

@error404: If it's not confidential, you might publish it online for us to try it on another computer.

Editing in LibreOffice has probably exacerbated the problem. File conversions always result in more complex documents. The following may help when you actually get your document back. https://superuser.com/questions/1686845/whats-the-file-size-limit-for-word/1686956

I personally recommend splitting documents with many pages and large size.

Another thing I've done with faulty files is to simply copy all the content to a new, fresh document. On rare occasions I've found there's some corruption in the original file that cannot be removed or cleared out, so the correct solution was to CTRL-A on the old doc, then CTRL-V in the new doc. Just grabbing the visible elements usually leaves behind the broken bits, in my experience. With a 1k page doc this may take a while (or crash and burn), but it's one of the methods I've found helpful for what you describe.

Have you tried Word recovery tools? This link says that their product (I am not associated with them) is the best in the world at recovering Word documents. There is a free download. There is also a list of competing products which you may find useful if the linked product does not help.

Unfortunately, all the recommendations are not working. I continue to search for a solution at this time.

Have you tried opening the file, doing a save as under a new name, closing it and then opening the new file? This is always my first go to with problem files and while it doesn't fix everything, it's always worth trying. Alternativly, open the file, remove all but the first 100 pages or so, save as "part 1", then to the same for the next 100 pages or so until you have 10 separate documents each with 100 pages. Do you still have the problem? If yes, with all of them or just one? If the latter, then you know something in that section is causing the problem.
